# Not all Theano modules import correct;ly

Tags: python, theano

I installed the current Theano using pip install into Python 2.7.10. However, when I try to import theano-e.g. from theano import * - I get the error 'Cannot import name gof'. I have checked Theano's directory, and there is a gof folder, which contains the items expected for a module. What is missing/ incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with .theano folder permissions.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

And then, to fix the permissions:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup ~/.theano
```